# Org mode - storing LaTeX preview files in a separate directory

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

Let's say I am working with "file_name.org" file. When I use `C-c C-x C-l` to generate a LaTeX preview, it creates a png image and store in ltximg/ directory by default.

I would store the preview images per file. So I want `C-c C-x C-l` 
 to create a directory (if there isn't one) ltximg/file_name/ and store the image there.

I know that I have to manipulate `org-preview-latex-image-directory` variable, but I am not sure how. Could someone help me with this?

### Update

I defined the following function. This works changes the `org-preview-latex-image-directory` whenever an org file is opened. So if I am working with multiple org files, it gets confused. So I am trying to write a wrapper for `org-toggle-latex-fragment` function so that whenever `org-toggle-latex-fragment` is called, `latex-image-directory` function is called. But I am having some trouble implementing the argument, e.g., `C-u C-c C-x C-l`.

```
(defun latex-image-directory ()
  (require 'cl-lib)
  (setq file-name (nth 0 (last (split-string (buffer-file-name) "/"))))
  ;; slice the last 4 characters: ".org"
  (setq org-preview-latex-image-directory (concat "ltximg/" 
(cl-subseq file-name 0 -4) "/")) 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you could do I think. First, you could put a local file variable into your org-files. For example if you put this into an org-file file

```
# Local Variables:
# org-preview-latex-image-directory: "ltximg/2018-11-11/"
# End:
```

Then, all latex fragments for that file will go in there. If you want it to be dynamic and change per file, you could define a function like you described. Here is a version that uses builtin functions to do it. You would need to put this function into an init file.

```
(defun latex-image-directory ()
  "Return directory name to save Latex preview images in."
  (let ((file-name (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))))
    (concat
     (file-name-as-directory "ltximg")
     (file-name-as-directory
      (file-name-sans-extension file-name)))))
```

Then, you can do one of these. To make it just in one file:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq-local org-preview-latex-image-directory (latex-image-directory))
# End:
```

I would use setq-local here because I think that makes the value buffer local so it won't affect other files. Since you want different values for different files, it would be a mistake to set it globally.

To make it on every file, you could use an org-mode-hook function that runs when you open an org-file:

```
(defun modify-preview-dir ()
 (setq-local org-preview-latex-image-directory (latex-image-directory)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'modify-preview-dir)
```

Since this is just modifying a variable, you should not need to handle any prefix args, e.g.  C-u C-c C-x C-l, and it should not be necessary to wrap or advise any functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work, but it is worth to try...

Thanks to your hint, I search the variable `org-preview-latex-image-directory` using <kbd>C-h v</kbd>. And see that it is defined on `org.el`. It should be a string.

Use <kbd>M-x customize-variable</kbd> to search `org-preview-latex-image-directory`. Click in the STATE button, and select "Show saved lisp expression".

I would change the lisp expression to `(concat "ltximg/" (buffer-file-name))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made some progress. Please see my updated post.